# Building errors with Maven in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ojdbc

I have a little bit of problem with building my web project eith eclipse. The main problem is including ojdbc7.jar from oracle into project - namely in pom.xml. I have tried several hints from here, but nothing worked. Also there is a bunch of other errors that prevents a clean startup....

Could anyone have a suggestion? Any help appreciated, thanks.

There is a screenshot from eclipse: [eclipse screen](https://q0fcja.by3301.livefilestore.com/y3p7MevgjdeNw689_O93gY-w0WK35eWPDdkE5S3n5rtIyegLhoIpXO0ZXJ7PGMZMvkYep1zAII1AlluwrQMy1WP4VFJkBx9gv-HEA7fYkOAO4xLc38yEdjwPAu6IH5cFCVt_mTxGgm44Rr1etUVa7JRtBEqAx2JaoTEiEcY5DFuPEw/2016-01-22.png?psid=1)

and this is my repository with the project: [my repository](https://github.com/Rikky007/workspace/tree/master/MVCcdshop)

Comment: Provide some detail with your question: include a copy of your pom.xml, provide a list of the error messages, and there is no point in adding a link to an image that requires a Microsoft account in order to view. You have the option of attaching an image file as part of your question, suggest you update the question.

Comment: I doubt you could pull oracle version 12.1.0.1 jar file without setting up a local repository using Artifactory or Nexus.

Comment: I have a whole project (with the pom file) in that repository, can't you see?

Comment: I was referring to maven repository manager not your project repository. Your pom.xml is setup to pull all the jar files from `http://central.maven.org/maven2/`. This won't work for Oracle JDBC driver as it is not released there.

Comment: I was answering to earlier reply..... however I just solved it by installing it separately via cmd line, which I tried before also, but putting it manually in the repository isn't an option obviously.